# Получить значение из HTML с помощью Jsoup

Tags: android, html, xml, jsoup

Есть HTML.

```
<html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
      <current>
       <city id="693194" name="Solonytsivka">
        <coord lon="36" lat="50"></coord>
        <country>
         UA
        </country>
        <sun rise="2018-08-28T02:44:59" set="2018-08-28T16:28:24"></sun>
       </city>
       <temperature value="295.15" min="295.15" max="295.15" unit="kelvin"></temperature>
       <humidity value="35" unit="%"></humidity>
       <pressure value="1017" unit="hPa"></pressure>
       <wind>
        <speed value="3" name="Light breeze"></speed>
        <gusts></gusts>
        <direction value="100" code="E" name="East"></direction>
       </wind>
       <clouds value="0" name="clear sky"></clouds>
       <visibility value="10000"></visibility>
       <precipitation mode="no"></precipitation>
       <weather number="800" value="clear sky" icon="01d"></weather>
       <lastupdate value="2018-08-28T05:00:00"></lastupdate>
      </current>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Нужно достать "693194" и "Solonytsivka".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Element city = doc.selectFirst("current>city");
long id = Long.parseLong(city.attr("id"));
String name = city.attr("name");
```

Comment: Ёлки зелёные)) Огромное мерси!!! Провозился всё утро)) Ты крут!!!

Comment: @Ruslan Chepizhko, был рад помочь :D